# Why is thunderbird leaving its workspace when I click on a notification?

Tags: xfce, thunderbird, workspaces

On XFCE (Archlinux) I have the problem, that thunderbird leaves workspace 2 and comes to workspace 1, when I click on a "new email" desktop notification. I have tried to set thunderbird to stay "always on this workspace" but it did not help.

If this is a bug, could it be a thunderbird or an XFCE bug and can I somehow stop this behaviour?

I want thunderbird to be permanently open and maximized on workspace 2.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97918).

*Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Focus -> when a window raises itself*

in German:

*Einstellungen -> Feineinstellungen der Fensterverwaltung -> Fokus -> wenn sich ein Fenster hervorhebt*

Comment: But why does focus result in moving a window from its workspace?

Comment: I had the setting "move window to current workspace" selected

Comment: In French : "Paramètres -> Peaufinage des fenêtres" (not to be confused with "Paramètres -> Gestionnaire de fenêtres", which also has a "Focalisation" tab).